# Add event listeners, and use `scan` to keep a reduced state, then remove event listeners

Tags: rxjs

I am working on this sandbox here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-g7msgv?file=index.ts

What I am trying to do is:

1) Wait for onLogin event

2) While logged in, I want to `connectSocket()`, and whenever the socket gets disconnected, and the app is in the foreground, I want to re-`connectSocket()`. (in the sandbox I have stubbed out `connectSocket()` to a promise that just waits 5 sec)

3) I want to repeat step 2, until onLogout event comes in

I wrote this code here, please see the sandbox and start things off by pressing the "onLogin" button.

```
fromEvent(document, 'onLogin')
    .pipe(
        switchMap(() =>
            of({ isDisconnected: true, isInForeground: true }).pipe(
                mergeMap(data =>
                    concat(
                        fromEvent(document, 'onDisconnect').pipe(
                            mergeMap(() =>
                                data.isDisconnected = true
                            )
                        ),
                        fromEvent(document, 'onAppStateChange').pipe(
                            mergeMap(({ detail:{ state } }) =>
                                data.isInForeground = state === 'foreground'
                            )
                        ),
                    ).pipe(
                        mergeMap(({ isDisconnected, isInForeground }) => {
                            if (isDisconnected && isInForeground) {
                                return flatMap(() => connectSocket());
                            } else {
                                return EMPTY;
                            }
                        })
                    )
                ),
                takeUntil(fromEvent(document, 'onLogout'))
            )
        )
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

I use `switchMap` because while its running, I don't want any other login events to restart another flow.

I'm not able to get this working. I am new to rxjs.

Comment: I think you will have to attached logic to a onDisconnected event in order to trigger reconnect. But i don't see that in the current code

Comment: Thanks @FanCheung I have the `fromEvent(document, 'onDisconnect')` - but the thing is because I initialize it with both `isDisconnected` and `isInForeground` true, it should fall through and run the `connectSocket()` but its not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startWith` to Init the value and `combineLatest` will fire when either one of the event is triggered.

```
fromEvent(document, 'onLogin').pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
        combineLatest(
            fromEvent(document, 'onDisconnect').pipe(
                mapTo(true),
                startWith(true)
            ),
            fromEvent(document, 'onAppStateChange').pipe(
                map(e => e.detail === 'foreground'),
                startWith(true),
            )
        ).pipe(
            mergeMap(([isDisconnected, isInForeground]) =>
                isDisconnected && isInForeground ? connectSocket() : EMPTY
            ),
            takeUntil(fromEvent(document, 'onLogout'))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to set `isDisconnected` to `false` after calling the `connectSocket()` method?

Comment: There is no need to set it to false, because you not reusing this value.

Comment: Thanks @Fan - but the socket may disconnect in future, so I want it to repeat the watching. Meaning if `isDisconnected` is false, and `isInForeground` changes I dont want to do anything. I want to wait till it is disconnected AND the app is in foreground.

Comment: you can try add repeat() before takeUntil

Comment: But it seems to be repeating already, its a never ending observable it seems. Is there a way to make that `combineLatest` set the first element in the array to false from the outside? I was hesitating to introduce a `onConnect` and then or the `onDisconnec` with `onConnect`.

Comment: You can combineLatest all three state , onconnect, ondisconnect, and satechange

Comment: combineLatest(merge(connect,disconnect), appstate).pipe(map( ([connected,isForeground])=>.......

Comment: reactive functional style need time to get used to

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate you understanding, I'm having such a hard time with it! haha